# What is the average ice time for an NHL player?

Tags: ice-hockey

What is the formula for determining it myself?

Comment: The formula is: total ice time divided by the number of games played

Answer (score 1):

The time on ice for a player per game really determines on the player's level. Just like in any sport, the more a player is skilled, the more time he plays. In hockey, the issue is no different.

Usually, out of the 60 minutes, average players get around 22-24 minuets per game while the best usually go for 28-30 minutes. In fact, the minutes per ice per game leader of the 13/14 regular season, Ryan Suter, went for just under 30 minutes per game.

[Source](http://espn.go.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/timeonice/sort/avgTimeOnIce/seasontype/2).